# Pandoc and foreign characters

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I've been trying to use Pandoc to convert some Markdown into a PDF file. This is a sample that Pandoc will not convert for me:

```
# Header!

## Sub Header

themselves derived respectively from the Greek ἀναρχία i.e. 'anarchy'
```

That's just something I grabbed from the top of the wikipedia database dump. Pandoc doesn't like that at all. This is the error message it gives me:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ἀ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.53 ...es derived respectively from the Greek ἀ
```

Is there a command switch I can give it to get around this? I tried following the advice to do something like this, but it failed:

```
iconv -t utf-8 test.md | pandoc -o test.pdf
```

**Update** Before following John's advice below, [see this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pandoc-discuss/urzu6dQU_R4).

**Update 2** This is the command that ultimately got it working. Hopefully this will help someone:

`pandoc test2.md -o test2.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex --template=my.latex --variable mainfont="DejaVu Serif" --variable sansfont=Arial`

And this is the contents of `my.latex`:

```
\documentclass[$if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$$if(lang)$$lang$,$endif$$if(papersize)$$papersize$,$endif$]{$documentclass$}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{ucs}
$if(euro)$
  \usepackage{eurosym}
$endif$
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \setromanfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
$if(mainfont)$
    \setmainfont{$mainfont$}
$endif$
$if(sansfont)$
    \setsansfont{$sansfont$}
$endif$
$if(monofont)$
    \setmonofont{$monofont$}
$endif$
$if(mathfont)$
    \setmathfont{$mathfont$}
$endif$
\fi
$if(geometry)$
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
$if(natbib)$
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\usepackage{biblatex}
$if(biblio-files)$
\bibliography{$biblio-files$}
$endif$
$endif$
$if(listings)$
\usepackage{listings}
$endif$
$if(lhs)$
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=Haskell,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}}{}
$endif$
$if(highlighting-macros)$
$highlighting-macros$
$endif$
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
$endif$
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable}
$endif$
$if(graphics)$
\usepackage{graphicx}
% We will generate all images so they have a width \maxwidth. This means
% that they will get their normal width if they fit onto the page, but
% are scaled down if they would overflow the margins.
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}
$endif$
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={$author-meta$},
            pdftitle={$title-meta$},
            colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=$if(urlcolor)$$urlcolor$$else$blue$endif$,
            linkcolor=$if(linkcolor)$$linkcolor$$else$magenta$endif$,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
$if(links-as-notes)$
% Make links footnotes instead of hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
$if(strikeout)$
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% avoid problems with \sout in headers with hyperref:
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand{\sout}{}}
$endif$
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
$if(numbersections)$
$else$
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
$endif$
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\VerbatimFootnotes % allows verbatim text in footnotes
$endif$
$if(lang)$
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{$mainlang$}
\else
  \usepackage[$lang$]{babel}
\fi
$endif$
$for(header-includes)$
$header-includes$
$endfor$

$if(title)$
\title{$title$}
$endif$
\author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
\date{$date$}

\begin{document}
$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$

$for(include-before)$
$include-before$

$endfor$
$if(toc)$
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
}
$endif$
$body$

$if(natbib)$
$if(biblio-files)$
$if(biblio-title)$
$if(book-class)$
\renewcommand\bibname{$biblio-title$}
$else$
\renewcommand\refname{$biblio-title$}
$endif$
$endif$
\bibliography{$biblio-files$}

$endif$
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\printbibliography$if(biblio-title)$[title=$biblio-title$]$endif$

$endif$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$

$endfor$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the `--pdf-engine=xelatex` option.

Comment: That created the document, but now I have a bunch of blank characters where the greek word is supposed to be. I think it is not recognizing the characters in question.

Comment: The blank characters show up when you have a font selected which does not contain greek glyphs. Use the ``--variable mainfont="..."`` option on the command line. See http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html Example 14 (Xe)Latex

Comment: For [CJK language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters), you might want to use `-V CJKmainfont="..."` instead. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090656/6064933) here.

Comment: You can also use the `lang` variable as I have described in my answer.

Comment: This answer is incomplete (doesn't mention fonts) and no longer correct (should say --pdf-engine).

Answer (score 39):

By default, Pandoc use the `pdflatex` engine when converting markdown file to pdf files. `pdflatex` can not handle Unicode characters very smoothly as `xelatex`. You should try `xelatex` instead. **But**, merely using `xelatex` command is not enough. As is often the case, you need to choose a proper font which contains glyphs for the Unicode characters your want to typeset.

I am a Chinese user, so take Chinese for example. If you have a `test.md` which contains the following content:

> 你好汉字

you can use the following command to compile this markdown file:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont="KaiTi" test.md -o test.pdf
```

In the above command, `--pdf-engine=xelatex` is used to select the LaTeX engine (for the new version of Pandoc, [`--latex-engine` option is deprecated](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/issues/665)). `-V CJKmainfont="KaiTi"` is used to select the proper font which support Chinese. **For other languages, you may use the flag `-C mainfont="<FONT_NAME>"`.**

#### How to find a font which support your language

In order to find a font which supports your language, you need to know your [language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). Then, if you are on Linux system or on Windows systems with [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) installed. You can use the following command to find a valid font for you language:

```
fc-list :lang=zh #find the font which support Chinese (language code is `zh`)
```

The output on my Linux system is shown below[image]

If you choose to use, e.g. the font `Source Han Serif CN`, then use the following command to compile your markdown file:

```
 pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont="Source Han Serif CN" test.md -o test.pdf
```

Comment: See [Pandoc with Chinese](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-with-Chinese) for more info.

Comment: XD. However, for me I need to use `mainfont` instead of `CJKmainfont`.

Comment: It is not true that `pdflatex` can not handle Unicode characters.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, is that true? I am not an expert at LaTeX. But `xelatex` seems the option when dealing with Unicode characters.

Comment: LaTeX was designed before Unicode, so it had only support for 256-character coding tables, however as it was possible to switch coding tables and fonts dynamically under the hood, it was completely normal to supply UTF-8 encoded input to LaTeX compiler, translation was performed by packages such as `inputenc` and `fontenc`.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, thanks for the information. I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE:** the answer below seems to be valid for pandoc 1.x but with later versions the syntax has changed

---

Coming back to this post in five years time and the issue is still there. The command

```
pandoc -s test.md -t latex -o test.pdf
```

fails when `test.md` contains text with non-latin characters, Greek, Cyrillic, CJK, Hebrew and Arabic included.

LaTeX was designed before Unicode and its support for different character sets is robust in some areas but far from comprehensive, so the advice to use XeLaTeX is valid yet requires one to choose the main font carefully, since there is no automatic choice.

Below is a small taxonomy of possible issues and some solutions. **All tested with Pandoc 1.19**.

### Cyrillic

Support for Cyrillic alphabet in LaTeX is provided via T2A font encoding.

Consider a small sample:

```
# Header

## Subheader

Tetris (Russian: Тетрис) quoting Wikipedia is a tile-matching puzzle 
video game
```

Running this example with pandoc would fail with:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Т (U+422)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
```

A fix is available as `fontenc` option is a predefined variable in `default.latex` template.

Running this example with

```
pandoc -t latex -o tetris.pdf -V fontenc=T2A cyrillic.md
```

would produce correct rendering

[image: Text with cyrillic characters rendered correctly]

This however would not handle other language features correctly such as  hyphenation. A better way would be to use Babel and have it select the correct font encoding.

```
pandoc -t latex -o tetris.pdf -V lang -V babel-lang=russian cyrillic.md
```

Or to switch languages with Babel commands inside Markdown

```
# Header

## Subheader

Tetris (Russian: \foreignlanguage{russian}{Тетрис}) quoting Wikipedia 
is a tile-matching puzzle video game
```

And run with

```
pandoc -t latex -o tetris.pdf -V lang -V babel-lang=english \
       -V babel-otherlangs=russian cyrillic2.md
```

### Greek

The example in the original post contains characters both from the main and extended Greek Unicode codepages.

Anyway, the widely used LGR greek font encoding is not covered by LaTeX 3 project and is classified as a *local* encoding, i.e. it may vary from site to site and from system to system according to the [LaTeX Encoding Guide](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf).

On TeX Live the following packages need to be installed: `texlive-greek-inputenc`, `texlive-greek-fontenc` and `texlive-cbfonts`. *Note that you need Babel 3.9 or later*.
However the result of

```
pandoc -t latex -o anarchy.pdf -V fontenc=LGR greek.md
```

may appear unexpected.

[image: Text with both Greek and Latin characters typed as Greek]

In order to correct this issue one has to setup LaTeX Babel package correctly. And insert commands to switch between the languages in the original text:

```
# Header!

## Sub Header

themselves derived respectively from the Greek \textgreek{ἀναρχία} 
i.e. 'anarchy'
```

Compiling this with the following command

```
pandoc -s greek2.md -t latex -V fontenc=T2A -V lang -V babel-lang=english \
    -V babel-otherlangs=greek -o greek.pdf
```

would produce the output exactly as you would expect it to be:

[image: Text with greek characters rendered correctly]

#### XeLaTeX

All of this would not be needed if we were using XeLaTeX.

Just running the original example with

```
pandoc -s greek.md --latex-engine=xelatex -t latex -o greek.pdf
```

would produce

[image: Text with Greek characters omitted]

Because the font does not contain anything in the greek character positions the output contains some white space instead.

Selecting one of the popular fonts as the new `mainfont` would help a bit

```
pandoc -s greek.md --latex-engine=xelatex \
    -V mainfont="Liberation Serif" -t latex -o greek.pdf
```

[image: Text with only basic Greek characters rendered correctly]

However characters from the extended Greek codepage such as the *small letter alpha with psili accent* are not rendered.

The [Font Setup for Greek with XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/language/greek/greek-fontenc/greek-euenc-doc.pdf) Guide suggests to use DejaVu, Libertine or Free font families.

Indeed with `DejaVu Serif`, `Linux Libertine O` as well as `Tempora` and perhaps some other fonts, the result would be as expected. See below the rendering with XeLaTeX and Linux Libertine fonts.

```
pandoc -s greek.md --latex-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Linux Libertine O" \
      -t latex -o greek.pdf
```

[image: Text with Greek characters rendered correctly with XeLaTeX and Libertine fonts]

Comment: That 'babel-lang' option it the only thing that worked for me, thanks! It is not directly mentioned in the official pandoc documentation

Answer (score 5):

Works for Cyrillic characters

```
pandoc myfile.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont=Arial
```

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason after checking updates and installing packages this command stopped work. I have removed Pandoc (v2.16.2) and MikTeX (v21.8) and re-installed again. After that I check for updates, but stop to install new packages. And it works again. Maybe my comment will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--latex-engine=xelatex`, as said before, but the best I have found is to use the `lang` variable to specify the document language in the header, like this: `lang: ru-RU`. A working example on my debian workstation:

```
---
title: Lady Macbeth de Mzensk (Chostakovitch, livret d'Alexandre Preis, 1934)
lang: ru-RU
---

# Acte I / Tableau 1

*[Народ ненадежный]*  
Ха, ха, ха, ха, ха, ха, ха. *[...]* Чуыствуем  
На кого ты нас покидаешь?  
Без хозяина будет скучно,  
скучно, тоскливо, безрадостно.

Не работа. Без тебя невеселье. Воз вращайся  
Как можно скорей, скорей !
```

Then you can launch:

```
$ pandoc -o your-file-output.pdf your-source-file.md
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LaTeX intermediate output, then you can use inline `\mbox{t\'ext}` to get accented characters. Without the `\mbox{}`, the backslash often isn't interpreted correctly by the Pandoc parser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to get mathematical symbols to show up in the output.

As others have mentioned, with recent pandoc versions (v2.2.3.2 in my case) the option to use is `pdf-engine=xelatex`. I did not need to specify a font in this case:

```
pandoc -o MyDoc.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex  MyDoc.md
```

I did get an error that the latinmodern-math font was missing. I installed it using:

```
tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```