# pandoc does not recognize Chinese characters

Tags: markdown, pandoc, cjk, xelatex

I want to compile, with `pandoc`, a Markdown document containing CJK elements (Chinese, actually). 
It was stated [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178084/pandoc-and-foreign-characters) that `--latex-engine=xelatex` option allows `pandoc` to compile Unicode characters.

However, I tried
cjk.md:

```
Hello
你好
```

compiled with (in bash)

```
pandoc -s -o cjk.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex cjk.md
```

But the resulting `.pdf` has only `Hello` shown, while `你好` was missing. 
Have I missed something? 
`pandoc` is updated; I'm using Macbook Air (bought 2012), updated to Sierra. 
I have properly installed `xelatex` (in MacTex I suppose), since when I used `texstudio` to compile `xelatex`, there was no problem.

Comment: maybe font missing? or modify the pandoc template with which the latex is generated, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex (also try `-o cjk.tex`, then use `xelatex cjk.tex` to debug the issue)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved. Tl;dr: it's not enough to set compiler to be `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`; one has to include package `xeCJK` as well, but for where it should be, see below.

---

**Edit**: the below can also be achieved by setting these [pandoc template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) variables:

```
---
CJKmainfont: STSong
CJKoptions:
  - BoldFont=STHeiti
  - ItalicFont=STKaiti
---

Hello 你好
```

---

In my case, `pandoc` reads a `.md`, converts it to be a `.tex`, and call compiler to compile that to be a `.pdf`. 
Thus, in theory, what I can do normally with a tex-like compiler, can be done with `pandoc` as well --- it is only that I have to specify required template.

The `pandoc` calls its own latex template, which we can `cat` in the terminal by a prewritten command:

```
pandoc -D latex > default.latex
```

This essentially copies a new file `default.latex` to `.` (current directory). 
It is this I now modify. 
Append this option to `pandoc` when compiling:

```
--template=my-directory/my-template.latex
```

In the past I type Chinese characters (or more generally, CJK), I use a template beginning with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}% use Latin font whenever possible
\usepackage{fontspec}% set Chinese fonts, as follows
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=STHeiti]{STXihei}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}
% .... whatever xeCJK commands you use
```

The fonts should be those your system permits; these shown above are shipped with mac.

But when I simply pasted this into the pandoc-provied template, there were many cryptic error messages

```
option clash for package XXXX....
```

This was because the pandoc-proviede template already defined `xeCJK`. Indeed, search these lines:

```
$if(CJKmainfont)$
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[$for(CJKoptions)$$CJKoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmainfont$}
$endif$
```

These lines (quoted part) should be replaced by

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
% .... and so on, whatever you call from xeCJK
```

i.e., delete `if`, so that `xeCJK` is always executed; otherwise, `xeCJK` line will not be copied to the intermediate `.tex` file.
And also delete `\usepackage{fontspec}`, because it is called by `pandoc` by default, otherwise error message occurs for packages are called twice in the intermediate `.tex` file.

---

acknowledgement: [[1]](http://www.cnblogs.com/liuyangnuts/archive/2013/04/23/3038354.html) [[2]](http://jiangfeng.org/notes/2013/04/19/markdown-with-pdf.html) [[3]](https://afoo.me/posts/2013-07-10-how-to-transform-chinese-pdf-with-pandoc.html)

Sorry I didn't keep track of every websites from which I referenced, but none gets it all right anyway, or are outdated. 
Of most help is [mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21), who suggested in the comment that I output `.tex` *to debug*, after which I found `xeCJK` was not included.

I have spent some 10+ hrs on this issue, but from now on I can happily type Chinese in a markdown file. 
I have wrote this down for poor posterity's sake.

Comment: glad you got it working! i'm not familiar with chinese latex, but i know pandoc... so see my edit :)

Comment: it is very kind of you sir. I know that one can probably set these sort of things in the very beginning of document like such, but I didn't know they are `CJKmainfont` and `CJKoptions`. Since I don't change fonts from time to time, for me its is okay to written down them in the common template (copied one). In addition, it looks more pleasing if Latin fonts are used whenever possible.