# How to write Chinese quotes in Bookdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I had tested in bookdown template, and found that `“”`, which is Chinese quotes, would be translated to ``` `` ```,`''`。 But if you write `“”` in a block or other `begin`,`end` blocks, the Chinese quotes, `“”`, would not be translated to ``` `` ```,`''`。So you will get different Chinese quotes, in the final pdf file. Can I set in some place to turn off such translation? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Is it necessary to use `bookdown` or does the same happen with standard `rmarkdown`?

Comment: @RalfStubner , The full example is here https://github.com/bubifengyun/deepin-bible .I will try write a minimal, complete example. Thank you.

Comment: I had find that, it is pandoc's issue. here is some topic.

- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/84
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Summary_table
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178084/pandoc-and-foreign-characters
- https://github.com/odkr/pandoc-quotes/blob/master/man/pandoc-quotes.rst

I will try. Thank you.

Comment: As https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/84 , maybe I should check rmarkdown to disable smart.

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use another method.

```
% 解决双引号不一致的问题。
\newcommand\cqh{“} % chinese quote head
\newcommand\cqt{”} % chinese quote tail
```

or add space after ``` ``'' ```. The solution is not very good. I add `md_extensions: -smart` make no sense.

For English, ``` `` '' ``` works very well, but In Chinese, it  becomes ugly.  Hope pandoc become good enough.